# Can we create users in Keycloak by sending a json array containing more than 2 user info?

Tags: java, keycloak, keycloak-services

I was able to create user in Keycloak by posting a json containing only 1 user using postman.

> http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/master/users

But when i tried to create more than 1 user by passing a json array of more than 1 record i am  getting a 500 Internal server error

```
[
  {
    "username": "user1",
    "firstName": "John",
    "attributes": {
      "pl_uid": null
    },
    "credentials": [
      {
        "temporary": true,
        "type": "password",
        "value": "ares2012"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "username": "1000195",
    "firstName": "Matt",
    "attributes": {
      "pl_uid": null
    },
    "credentials": [
      {
        "temporary": true,
        "type": "password",
        "value": "rx3o0t9f"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Is there any way by which we can send a json array to keycloak and create users there?

Comment: Your payload helped me to create my json file to import in the keycloak's container

Comment: where can i find the user-json for keycloak? I am also looking for similar functionality so that using "partal import" i can add users.

Answer (score 6):

Please have a look on the discussion added in Keycloak mailing list

> Just double checked the approach I suggested. I thought we had made
> it possible to import users into an existing realm, but that's not the
> case. You have to create the whole realm. It's still possible to do it
> this way, first create the realm and add an example user. Stop the
> server and run it again with:

```
 bin/standalone.sh -Dkeycloak.migration.action=export -Dkeycloak.migration.provider=dir -Dkeycloak.migration.realmName=<realm name> -Dkeycloak.migration.dir=<dir name>
```

> - Replace realm name and dir name
>
> In dir name you should then get a few json files. You can then
> update realm name-users-0.json to add the users you want to import.
>
> As Bill points out the admin client could be a good alternative
> approach. We also have a Java client that makes it simpler to use.
> Have a look at the admin-client example.

So this URL can help. Have a look at [this link](http://lists.jboss.org/pipermail/keycloak-user/2015-May/002145.html)

Another option is using partialImport API for importing users (use admin user token):

```
access_token=`curl --data "grant_type=password&username=admin&password=admin&client_secret=secret&client_id=admin-cli" http://localhost:8180/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token| jq -r .access_token`

curl -X POST -H 'Accept: application/json' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H "Authorization: Bearer $access_token"  --data "@$PWD/myrealm-users-0.json"  http://localhost:8180/auth/admin/realms/myrealm/partialImport
```

Comment: Seems not working anymore with 19.0.1. Error: {"error":"RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: http://localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/myrealm/partialImport"}%

Comment: I echo the same, not working with keycloak 20.0 version. Looking for some options bulk importing users.

Answer (score 5):

After checking [Keycloak's REST API](https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/3.0/rest-api/index.html#_users_resource) doesn't look like bulk/batch requests for creating users are accepted. The only solution would be to send the `POST` request for every user.

This is not surprising, HTTP is not prepared for this kind of requests:

> As HTTP does not provide proper guidance for handling batch/bulk requests and responses.

from [this RESTful guide](https://opensource.zalando.com/restful-api-guidelines/). Have a look to it, it's really usefull in REST devlopments.

Answer (score 0):

I checked the `paritalImport` approach as suggested by others, it seems not available anymore in later versions such as 19.0.1. The error message is something like {"error":"RESTEASY003210: Could not find resource for full path: localhost:8080/auth/admin/realms/myrealm/partialImport"}%.

So I invoke Keycloak API to create users, one by one though. But as long as we can use a program to do it, it's also acceptable.

For example, we can write some java code to invoke the creating user API:

```java
    public String createUser(UserPayload user) throws IOException {
        var url = "https://keycloak.jiwai.win/auth/admin/realms/UniHeart/users";
        var payload = java.lang.String.format("{\"firstName\":\"Sergey\",\"lastName\":\"Kargopolov\", \"email\":\"%s\", \"enabled\":\"true\", \"username\":\"%s\", \"credentials\":[{\"type\":\"password\",\"value\":\"%s\",\"temporary\":false}]}", user.getEmail(), user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
        return this.jsonRequest(url, payload).toString();
    }
```

The above code is merely calling the create user API. But to call it successfully we need firstly got the admin access token:

```java
    public KeycloakAccessTokenPayload getAdminAccessToken() throws IOException {
        var username = System.getenv("KC_ADMIN");
        var password = System.getenv("KC_PASSWORD");

        System.out.println(java.lang.String.format("username = %s; password = %s", username, password));

        var mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        var body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, java.lang.String.format("username=%s&password=%s&grant_type=password&client_id=admin-cli", username, password));
        var request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("https://keycloak.jiwai.win/auth/realms/master/protocol/openid-connect/token")
                .method("POST", body)
                .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
                .build();
        var response = client.newCall(request).execute();

        var s = Objects.requireNonNull(response.body()).string();

        System.out.println(java.lang.String.format("token response = %s", s));

        return JsonHelper.parseFrom(s);
    }
```

And then pass the admin access token to the target API by setting the HTTP header:

```java
    public Response jsonRequest(String url, String payload) throws IOException {
        var mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json");
        var body = RequestBody.create(mediaType, payload);
        var request = new Request.Builder().url(url).method("POST", body).addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json").addHeader("Authorization", java.lang.String.format("Bearer %s", getAdminAccessToken().access_token)).build();
        var res = client.newCall(request).execute();

        System.out.println(java.lang.String.format("jsonRequest response = %s", res.toString()));

        return res;
    }
```

The fully working example is here: https://github.com/Jeff-Tian/keycloak-springboot/blob/main/src/main/java/com/example/keycloakspringboot/KeycloakHelper.java#L29